# Access AAD Logs across tenants

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Is there a possibility to leverage Azure Lighthouse to access AAD logs from a different tenant? Also, let's say there are three tenants, prod, staging and dev, how can we stream AAD logs from all the three tenants to one location?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Sentinel with Azure Lighthouse might be one potential option for you to look for.

https://blog.cyberproof.com/blog/deploying-microsoft-azure-sentinel-siem-in-a-multi-tenancy-environment-part-1

Good luck !